# Java thread safe counter own lock implementation

Tags: java, thread-safety, locking, counter, synchronized

I just thought about how to lock a variable such as an int while modifying it from different threads. I don't wont to use it that way, and I know about the synchronized keyword in Java, but I want to learn about that and how this works in general.

So that is my code:

```
private int i = 0;
private int lock = 0;

public void count(int lock) {
    while (true) {
        if (this.lock == 0) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        if (this.lock == lock) {
            i ++;
            this.lock = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The question: Does it work? Is it this counter thread safe? If yes: Does the synchronized keyword a simmilar job? If no: Why not?

Edit: I forgot to mention that each thread calls the count method with a different lock value.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` is your friend here. This doesn't look like a good idea at all... (it's not clear what you expect the `lock` parameter to the method to be, for one thing...)

Comment: I just edited the question. Each thread uses a different lock parameter

Comment: it won't work for so many reasons...

Comment: Well there's basically no memory barrier in place there, so it doesn't look safe at all. It entirely possible for two threads to each see the `lock` value they just wrote, and then update `i` unsafely. Fundamentally, trying to come up with your own locking primitives like this is a really bad idea unless you're a fully-fledged Java memory model expert (which I'm certainly not). AtomicInteger really is the way to go... or use a separate `Object` to synchronize on.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's why I check twice.

Comment: @JonSkeet AtomicInteger cannot be used instead of locks, CAS doesn't lock. I believe that the OP is trying to implement a semaphore manually

Comment: @SleimanJneidi that's what I am trying :)

Comment: @SleimanJneidi: The OP wants a thread-safe counter, as far as I can see - for which `AtomicInteger` is entirely suitable. I see no indication of a semaphore in the normal sense - but every indication of a method attempting to implement `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet`. If semaphore behaviour is requested, the OP should make that much, much clearer - and then use a `Semaphore`.

Comment: @JonSkeet well yeah, AtomicInteger allows you to mutate an int safely,but the question is not worded properly

Comment: @stonar96 you trying what? implementing a semaphore?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi basically yes. Just to learn about that topic ... But I thought about an own solution, and I don't see a chance that two threads will write and read the same lock value at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that 'no' there's no guarantee on thread safety there.

The longer answer is that you need to look at the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) to understand why. Part of the problem is that different threads may not see changes at the same time. The memory model only guarantees that a read after a write sees the updated value in the same thread that did the write, unless a memory barrier is crossed. Another thread may not see that update even though it performs the read after the other thread has performed the write. Unless you describe the variable using the `volatile` keyword. Or use the `synchronized` keyword to ensure that only a single thread is updating the value. This behaviour allows the Java runtime to optimise the code, perhaps by inlining things it notices are constant in a loop, and also to use native assembly language which *doesn't* provide synchronicity guarantees but which is demonstrably faster.

Another part of the problem is that when two updates which occur on different threads at the same time the only way to be sure that the same result is made available to both threads is to use the corresponding low-level assembly language instructions - which might be called compareAndSet, compareAndSwap or testAndSet.

So, to go for, the code you've written, the equivalent of this sort of execution order is entirely possible (where T1 and T2 as separate threads)...

```
// assuming i begins at 0.
T1: if this.lock == true
T2: if this.lock == true
T1: this.lock = lock
T1: if this.lock == lock     // evaluates to true
T2: if this.lock == lock     // evaluates to true
T1: this.lock = lock
T2: this.lock = lock
```

It's actually more complicated because you can't say that each of those instructions is a single instruction on the CPU. Fundamentally, you can have two threads executing some kind of updates at the same time, with all the attendant results around double or lost updates.

Even simpler answer: use the Atomic primitives provided in `java.util.concurrent` for thread-safe counters.